# Regex group is matching quotes when I don't want it to

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression:

```
"([^"\\]|\\.)*"|(\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FLjssEapxGFG6uBf)

But the problem is, when I have an input like `"foo"` and I use a matcher to go through the groups, the first group it finds is `"foo"` when I want it to be `foo`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I'm using Java and I just fixed it

```
"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|(\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GCQ7crf_QwAyGO3n)

The first capturing group wasn't including the `*` which is the whole string. I enclosed it within a capturing group and made the inner existing one a non capturing group.

EDIT: Actually no... it's working in the online regex debuggers but not in my program...

Comment: The first group is 1-character long and does not allow `"`, so it's impossible that it can match something like `"foo"`. The second group (the one with `\S+`) can match `"foo"`, but it should not be triggered here. What language are you using? Can you provide a snippet of code that shows the problem?

Comment: Capture the contents of the double quoted literal and if it matched grab it. Also, consider unrolling the pattern: `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"|(\S+)`

Comment: I'd use `([^"\s]\S*)` instead of `(\S+)` to avoid ambiguity.What comes after `"foo"`? Could it be not-whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the contents of the double quoted literal pattern (Branch 1) and if it matched grab it.

Also, consider unrolling the pattern:

```
 "([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"|(\S+)
```

In Java:

```
String pat = "\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\\"]*)*)\"|(\\S+)";
```

Note that patterns like `(A|B)*`  often cause a stack overflow issue in Java, that's why an unrolled version is preferable.